# How to upload application with duplicate package name with diffrent keystore.

Tags: google-play, package, android-package-managers

Hi I have application released in playstore.
I want to remove that application from play store and upload a new application with same package name and different keystore is it possible?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do that. Package names are globally unique, so you cannot have two of the same ones. Even if you do delete the application, the app will still exist (in an unpublished state), it just will not be visible to anyone.